# Calculating average time between events in a flat table with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In the sample MySQL database below, I'd like to analyse this data but my SQL skills let me down.

```
=========================================    
activity_type  email        activity_date
email_sent     a@mail.com   2013-12-01
email_sent     b@mail.com   2013-12-01
email_sent     c@mail.com   2013-12-01
email_click    a@mail.com   2013-12-04
email_click    b@mail.com   2013-12-05
email_reply    a@mail.com   2013-12-07
=========================================
```

Using SQL, how would you calculate the average length of time it took for an email to be clicked? (The answer is 3.5 days. Only emails ***a*** and ***b*** were clicked, and they were clicked 3 and 4 days later, respectively.)

Would your SQL query also allow us to calculate the average time it took for an email to be replied to, even though there is only on instance of this occurring?

Thanks in advance for helping out a super-n00b.

Comment: Have you looked at SQL [AVG function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp)?

Comment: Sure Harry, though I'm not that advanced at manipulating it to do what I want.
For example, I could average out the activity_date column fairly easily. But how to take it a step further and only average out the difference in dates when certain conditions exist in the first two columns is beyond me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT avg(datediff(t2.activity_date, t1.activity_date))
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t1.activity_type = 'email_sent'
  AND t2.activity_type = 'email_click'
```

To calculate reply time just change the relevant `t2.activity_type` field.

Comment: I can't upvote, but this worked, Niels. Thanks!
[...and thanks for making my question title better too.]

Comment: You're welcome, and you can mark it as the 'Accepted Answer' by clicking the checkmark left of here  :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to join the lines of the sent event to the lines of the clicked event. then calculate the difference between the dates in days, then calculated the average.

```
SELECT AVG(e2.activity_date - e.activity_date) avg_gap
FROM email e
JOIN email e2 on (e.email = e2.email)
WHERE e.activity_type= 'email_sent'
AND e2.activity_type= 'email_click'
```